# Remove linux wall message

Tags: linux, terminal

a wall message is stuck in linux wall when someone connects to the server, how do I reset/remove it? The man page for "wall" does not help me.
I have root permission.

Thank you

Comment: What do the messages say by the way?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you receive `wall` messages on your terminal whenever someone connects to the server and you don't want this, then try using `mesg(1)` to disable write access to your terminal by other users, like `$ mesg n`. That's assuming the messages originate from some other user though.

It might be better to figure out why you get those messages though, if you don't want them.

All `mesg` does is to alter the file permissions on your tty (running `$ tty` will give you its filename) by the way. Running `$ chmod a-w $(tty)` will block all `wall` messages, even if they come from the same user. That also means you might miss important messages though.

Comment: ok, let me understand, this wall messsage is an automatic one, from a regression test, when the regression is running it gives this message, "reserved for blah run". The test is closed but the message is stuck.
I dont want to remove permission for users to write a message to the wall, just this one reset.
with `mesg(1)` it prevents people for writing on the wall, but I dont think it is what I want now

Comment: @thahgr: There's no way to remove the message from the terminal once it's been written. All you can do is to prevent it from being written in the first place. Do you know if the test is running as a different user?

Comment: @Ulfazer, you mean as a different user in the server? I think yes. What do I do in this case?
The test is not currently running

Comment: @thahgr: Yup, as a different user on the server. If you'd be okay with silencing that user completely so it can't use `wall` to write to other users, then it would probably work to remove that user from the `tty` group (if you can do that). Might be better to talk to the regression test guys though.

Comment: Hmm, I'm actually not sure if that will work though, so don't quote me on it. `wall` seems to be executable by everyone.

Comment: @Ulfazer: I dont want to silence that user completely..
Simple way, but can I just post an empty message instead?
In any case, thanks for your time to see this through

Comment: @thahgr: You might still get the "Broadcast message from..." part if it's using `wall`. If it's using `write(1)` instead (write to specific user), then it should be possible to change it to only write the message to specific users who want the message. Do you know how it sends the message?

Comment: No problem! Feel free to post updates.

Comment: no I dont know how it sends it, if its wall or write. I will check this out.